# Why is my yeoman build failing?

Tags: yeoman

This is the last part of my build:

```
Generating the cache manifest
  - Command: phantomjs /Users/ablair/tmp/yeo2/yeoman/cli/lib/support/confess.js http://localhost:3501 appcache /Users/ablair/tmp/yeo2/yeoman/cli/lib/support/confess.json

Writing to manifest.appcache...
undefined:0 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

Full log: http://pastebin.com/qECNNGSX

The result is that a server is apparently running, I can visit the localhost url but the javascript isn't combined or minified. I'm using a fresh install. This happens whether or not I've added any of my own JavaScript into the boilerplate init code. I am opting into Twitter Bootstrap but not plugins or anything else, FYI when I do yeoman init.

Compass version: Compass 0.13.alpha.0 (Markab)
Node version: v0.8.14
Yeoman version: yeoman v0.9.5 (I have tried the default and cloned from github)

Comment: What happens when you run `yeoman server`? It sounds like `require.js` isn't being included in the page.

Comment: So you don't get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: No, not when I run server, only build. I just did another `init` and I am saying no to requirejs, but is it mandatory? I can appreciate it's value for a complex project but in this case I have a fairly light app and I don't need MVC or anything. Just a few script files but want to benefits of the package manager for future enhancements and the combine/minify conveniences. http://pastebin.com/bMxdn2D5

Comment: I also just tried `init` and opted into twitter bootstrap, not the js plugins, yes to requirejs and no to everything else and I still get the original error with `yeoman build`

Comment: I replicated your steps but didn't get any errors. I'd recommend completely removing all traces of yeoman, running the audit script and then install v0.9.5 via npm. And no, you don't need require JS, I'm using yeoman for a project at the moment without it.

Comment: So i tried reinstalling all yeoman related stuff but no luck on OS X 10.6. I have a 10.8 partition, works fine there, just tried it.

Comment: That's odd, I was definitely thinking this was an environment issue. Sorry, I wont be able to help much more from here. I'd recommend digging into the manifest task (`yeoman/cli/tasks/manifest.js`) and see if you get it to output more debug info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had an old Sencha Touch SDK in my path which contains a file (if not a binary) of phantomjs. That version was taking precedence (due to order of path entries in my ~/.bash_profile). I just removed the old SDK from my path and it started working. I proved that this was what was happening, by running `which phantomjs` – which printed out the version that was in the unrelated directory rather than the one in /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have an outdated version of PhantomJS.

Go to ([PhantomJS - Scriptable Headless Browser](http://phantomjs.org)) and download latest.